# How do I count events between start and end times with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a `datetime` index:

```
2019-09-23 11:34:51 55f0da3f10c
2019-09-24 10:53:53 c4424f9f273
2019-10-02 19:52:21 eca42947ece
2019-10-05 16:59:26 5577300335e
```

I would like to count, for all days in the dataset, how many "events" there are between 7pm and 7am. I have

```
grouper = Grouper(level="datetime", freq="1H")
days = df.groupby([grouper]).size().reset_index(name='activity')
```

but I don't know how to specify the time period.

Answer (score 1):

The time period can be specified by `pd.Grouper(freq='12H', base=7)`, where `base` is the offset with regard to the selected frequency. In this case we have 7 hours of offset.

This apparently resamples the `df`, but the relevant rows can be filtered:

```
time_grouper = pd.Grouper(freq='12H', base=7)
grouped = df.groupby(time_grouper).size()
time_filtered = grouped.between_time(start_time='19:00', end_time='07:00',
                                include_start=True, include_end=False)
event_filtered = time_filtered[time_filtered > 0]
```